# Twitter bootstrap padding not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to position my content under my navbar and when I add the `padding-top: 60px;` it works but pushes the navbar down. I also need the background to be at the top of the page behind the navbar. How can I fix this? The content for the page including the navbar AND background are pushed down but I need the navbar and the background at the top of the page and only the content pushed down.

```css
body {
    padding-top: 65px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#header {
  background-color: grey;
  opacity: .7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#logo a {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: 'DIN 1451 Std Engschrift';
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#slide1 {
  width: 100%;
  background: url('sunrise.png') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40px 0 260px 0;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
        <div class="content">
    <nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
      <div id="logo">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar Logo</a>
      </div>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      <div id="logo">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#slide3">How it Works</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#slide4">For Landlords</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">F.A.Q</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#pricingslide">Pricing</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
 </div>
    <body>
      <div id="slide1">
  <div class="content">
    <h1 id="headline">Use Your Rent To Buy A Home</h1>
    <p id="subtitle">Build a credit history, create a down payment,<br> all by just making rent payments thru LikeHome</p>
    <h3>Find out how soon you can become a homeowner?</h3>
    <%= render '_how_much_buying_form.html.erb' %>
  </div>
</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: set a `margin: 0;` on your navbar

Comment: didnt fix it. same problem. it moved the navbar down AND their is a whitespace over my background. I need the background to stay at the top and the content to move down

Comment: can you create a fiddle to show more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this work for you?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#slide1 {
  background: url('http://res.cloudinary.com/sayob/image/upload/v1526907328/483257_vwhhfw.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 700px;
  padding: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div id="logo">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar Logo</a>
  </div>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#slide3">How it Works</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#slide4">For Landlords</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">F.A.Q</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#pricingslide">Pricing</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid" id="slide1">
  <h1 id="headline">Use Your Rent To Buy A Home</h1>
  <p id="subtitle">Build a credit history, create a down payment,<br> all by just making rent payments thru LikeHome</p>
  <h3>Find out how soon you can become a homeowner?</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to correct the HTML markups. All html contents must be inside  tag. Wrap the elements in a body tag, and create another div or section for contents followed by the header. And give padding to that div.